# K-Nearest Neighbour Classifier accuracy

Tags: matlab, confusion-matrix

I followed an example of the MATLAB KNN classifier with 10 fold cross validation, I am lost at the stage of computing the model's performance, Please kindly look at my code below and advice on how i can correctly get the accuracy of my classification in percentage (%), I dont get the cVError = 1-mean(errorMat) part. Secondly, the fitcknn and knn.predict functions were used to train and test the model, I need help on how i'll create my own functions to do the same tasks. Thank you.

```
indices = crossvalind('kfold',labels,10);
confusionMatrix = cell(1,1);
errorMat = zeros(1,10);
for i = 1:10
test = (indices==i);
train = ~test;
knn = fitcknn(data(train,:),labels(train),'NumNeighbors',kVal);
y = knn.predict(data(test,:));
index = cellfun(@strcmp,y,labels(test));
errorMat(i) = sum(index)/length(y);
confusionMatrix{i} = confusionmat(labels(test),y);
end

% Calculate misclassification error
cvError = 1-mean(errorMat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error computation**

The lines

```
index = cellfun(@strcmp,y,labels(test));
errorMat(i) = sum(index)/length(y);
```

computes the *success* rate of the *i*-th classification (between 0 and 1). The average *success* rate is then the mean of all the 10 success rates (one for each evaluation).

The line

```
cvError = 1-mean(errorMat);
```

is then the average *error* rate. For instance, if you have a success rate equal to 0 (=in average the classifier always fail), the error rate will be equal to 1, and *vice-versa*. This is called the [complementary event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event) probability.

**`fitcknn` and `knn.predict` implementation**

Native MATLAB functions are usually faster, since they are optimized and precompiled.
However, if you need to implement them by yourself (for a homework, for example), you should read the mathematical theory, then implement the logic step-by-step, although this could take time. You are of course invited to post a new question if you meet problems, with your tentative code.

There are of course several ways to do it (building a sorted distance vector for each prediction is one of the simplest), but the question is if you have performance requirements/limitations on the set of functions you can use.

Suggested links (basically the first results of a Google search):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm

http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/K-nearest_neighbor

http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~tinoosh/cmpe650/slides/K_Nearest_Neighbor_Algorithm.pdf